# cython hidapi write error

Tags: python, usb, cython, hidapi

I am trying to write to a USB device attached to raspberry pi 3 installed with raspbian.

Error:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    h.write([81 80 73 71 83 183 169 13])
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

---

code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import hid

h = hid.device()
h.open(0x0665, 0x5161)
h.set_nonblocking(1)  // Returns 0
h.write([0, 63, 35, 35] + [0] * 61) // Returns -1

h.write([81 80 73 71 83 183 169 13]) //Throws error above.
```

Whats wrong with this code? Based on the documentation in the library, it accepts any list of integers.

I used this as a ref: https://github.com/trezor/cython-hidapi/blob/master/try.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing comma separation in the list.

List should be `,`(comma) separated,

Change `h.write([81 80 73 71 83 183 169 13])`

to

`h.write([81, 80, 73, 71, 83, 183, 169, 13])`